# word similarty between mail adresses and names

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

My problem is little bit  different  from simple word similarty.The question is that is there any algorithm to use for calculating similarty between mail adress and name.

```
    for example:
    mail Abd_tml_1132@gmail.com
    Name Abdullah temel
    levenstein,hamming distance  11
    jaro distance  0.52
```

but most likely, this mail address belongs to this name.

Comment: Have you tried removing part of string after `@` and then apply similarity algo

Comment: This similartiy results've obtained as already removing this part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Direct package but this can solve your problem:

**Making email id into list**

```
a = 'Abd_tml_1132@gmail.com'
rest = a.split('@', 1)[0] # Removing @
result = ''.join([i for i in rest if not i.isdigit()]) ## Removing digits as no names contains digits in them
list_of_email_words =result.split('_') # making a list of all the words. The separator can be changed from _ or . w.r.t to email id
list_of_email_words = list(filter(None, list_of_email_words )) # remove any blank values
```

**Making Name to a list:**

```
b = 'Abdullah temel'
list_of_name_words =b.split(' ')
```

**Apply fuzzy match to both lists:**

```
score =[]
for i in range(len(list_of_email_words)):
    for j in range(len(list_of_name_words)):
        d = fuzz.partial_ratio(list_of_email_words[i],list_of_name_words[j])
        score.append(d)
```

Now you just need to check if any of the elements of `score` is greater than a threshold which can be defined by you. For example:

```
threshold = 70
if any(x>threshold for x in score):
    print ("matched")
```

Answer (score 0):

Fuzzywuzzy can help you with the required solution. First remove '@'and domain name from the string using regex. You will be having 2 string as follows afterwards -

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz as fz
str1 = "Abd_tml_1132"
str2 = "Abdullah temel"

count_ratio = fz.ratio(str1,str2)
print(count_ratio)
```

Output -

```
46
```